# How to run a background thread that get data from server and if response not null add data to listview in android

Tags: android

I am making a chat window there are two method one for sending message and one for receiving message.I want when i click on send button the method call and send message to server and a background thread create if there is any response message then add that message to the list.how can i do this?

I want if there is any response message then response message call a thread that check if there is any message receive then add this to listview if not then add nothing to the list.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//onCreate
new BackGroundLoginTask().execute();


//async task

public class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void >  
    {
      private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(PlacesList.this);

      protected void onPreExecute() 
      {

             Dialog.setMessage("Downloading");
             Dialog.show();
      }

      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
      {
         // write here the code to download  or to perform any background task.


         //perform background task
            return null;
    }

      protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
      {

          listview.setAdapter(new PlacesAdapter());
          Dialog.dismiss();  

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way of doing this is an AsyncTask by extensing the AsyncTask class and overriding the below methods:

// For getting the data from server runs in a seperate thread

```
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {         }
```

// For updating the UI if in case you want to show some data in between. Runs on UI Thread

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {        }
```

// For final updation of UI. Runs on UI Thread

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {         }
```

You may also want to have a look at the official documentation for this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: can you refer me a example of Asynk task?

Comment: Have a look At: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask

Answer (score 0):

What i see in this case is ,

You will have 3 classes.

class1 will extend AsyncTask and will have a logic to obtain new message from server.

class2 will periodically ping server to check if there is any new message.
If yes then it will send the broadcast.

class3 will act as an broadcast receiver.on receiving broadcast it will execute class3 to fetch message.onPostExecute method will return the message object,

Now you will show that message on Actual UI.

Hope this help.